# Entity Framework / Unit of Work Architecture Question

Tags: entity-framework, architecture

I'm very familiar with UoW, Repository Pattern, etc. but in seeing various implementations of the pattern for Entity Framework, I'm curious why anyone would have a Save or Add method on their repository. If you use the repository to get you a new instance of an object that I would imagine someone would already

```
public Customer GetNewCustomer()
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
     ... any initialization code here ...
    _context.Customers.AddObject(customer);
   return customer;
}
```

I know in some designs, you can simply use

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

and its not attached anywhere to the context. However I'm a fan of private constructors so there is a single point of instantiation for a Customer object. With that in mind wouldn't it makes sense to never have an add/save method on the repository when using a UoW pattern and only have this functionality on the IUnitOfWork interface?

Answer (score 1):

When I follow the Spring idiom in Java, units of work (and transactions) are associated with services.  They use model and persistence objects to fulfill a request.  Transactions are demarked using aspects.

I don't know whether .NET follows a similar idea, but it'd be worth exploring.  Have interface-based POCO services and let them own transactions.

Comment: In .Net it 'can' happen the same way. Aspects can be used as well as built in handling in an EF context, in addition to explicit code transaction usage. I'm no stranger to the UoW pattern, but its in conjunction with how the DbContext with the Entity Framework acts as part of it in a sense that I'm looking for opinions (thanks though!!)

Comment: .NET has Spring.NET - it is not so powerful like Spring in Java but it can handle transactions in AoP way. The problem is that it cannot be easily combined with Entity framework. You will have to move to NHibernate. Another problem is that you should have somebody who already did project this way in your team otherwise it will be very painful experience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your solution is correct. That will add empty customer to current unit of work. That means that later code will have a hard time if it decide not to save customer by the current unit of work.

It is quite common that repository have method to save entity. You are combining two patterns used in Domain driven design

- Repository
- Object factory

Repository's responsibility is to retrieve or store entities. Object factory's responsibility is to handle entity construction.

Btw. private constructor of your entity will not be accessible in your repository if repository is not the entity (which would be quite bad).

Comment: I shouldve shown the Customer.NewCustomer() above. I think the Context had me a bit confused on the best implementation of it since it contains a bit of its own UoW. By going through the repository for your C(rud) in this case gives you one location for your object needs in this case the create.  One could argue 'what if I need a stand alone customer object' then you can use the factory, but this case ensures its part of the context with no need for an add. A pure UoW would have .Add but the use of a context here also has its own object tracking hence a bit of the blurring .

Answer (score 1):

> ...wouldn't it makes sense to never have an add/save method on the
>   repository when using a UoW pattern and only have this functionality
>   on the IUnitOfWork interface?

Yes I think it makes sense to only have the Save method on the IUnitOfWork interface. However, I no longer use the repository pattern with EF. Instead, I now use [these](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) [variations](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) of the command & query patterns.

If you think about it, the EF DbContext is really doing 3 things: 1.) it functions as your repository for reading entity state, 2.) as your repository for mutating entity state, and 3.) as a UnitOfWork for tracking multiple changes and combining them into a single transaction to persist state mutations.

So, why not separate these 3 responsibilities into 3 different interfaces?

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    int SaveChanges();
}

public interface ICommandEntities : IQueryEntities
{
    void Create(Entity entity);
    void Update(Entity entity);
    void Purge(Entity entity);
}

public interface IQueryEntities
{
    IQueryable<AggregateRoot1> AggregateRoot1s { get; }
    IQueryable<AggregateRoot2> AggregateRoot2s { get; }
    IQUeryable<AggregateRootN> AggregateRootNs { get; }

    IQueryable<TEntity> EagerLoad<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> expression)
        where TEntity : Entity;
}
```

You can then implement these 3 interfaces on your DbContext class. This keeps the interfaces nice and segregated, and lets you dependency inject only those methods of the DbContext which you need.

For example, your domain should be persistence ignorant, right? In that case, don't give any of your domain classes dependencies on the IUnitOfWork interface. Instead, handle the IUnitOfWork in your IoC composition root (or in an MVC action filter). Then, your query and command handlers deal only with the ICommandEntities and IQueryEntities interfaces.

Comment: Someone once brought up a point that CQRS is being done nowhere outside of .net, while other strong architectural practices are and have been for some time. It made me think a bit about it but surely more curious as to 'why'

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT, CQRS is indeed being done outside of .net: http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/reactive-cqrs-application?utm_campaign=infoq_content&utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=feed&utm_term=global

Comment: sure, but this was also over two years ago :) Many of the top hits still are .NET based ones but glad to see _some_ mention of it outside of .net (although that article is tech agnostic IIRC)